# Joining selected columns from 2 tables ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to find a way to display selected columns from two tables. Table 1 is an inventory list and table 2 is a list of items requested by a customer.

Table 1: Inventory

| Code | Description | UnitPrice | QtyOnHand | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book | P200 | 100 | AV |
| 2 | bag | P300 | 120 | AV |
| 3 | pen | P20 | 90 | AV |
| 4 | eraser | P20 | 190 | AV |

Table 2: Order

| OrderItems | InvCode | QtyOrdered | Total | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2000 | OP |
| 1 | 2 | 20 | 6000 | OP |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 200 | OP |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 3000 | OP |
| 2 | 1 | 30 | 6000 | OP |

From this table, I want to print some selected data from **Order** table that has OrderItems code of 1, along with some data from **Inventory** table. How do I achieve this? do I need to use join? if so, how do I do it?

Note: The number in the headers are what table

Result:

| Code (2) | Description (1) | QtyOrdered (2) | UnitPrice (1) | Total (2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book | 10 | P200 | 2000 |
| 2 | bag | 20 | P300 | 6000 |
| 3 | pen | 30 | P20 | 200 |
| 2 | bag | 10 | P300 | 3000 |

also, can I data bind it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using datatables you can do something like it:

```
dt1.AsEnumerable().Join(dt2.AsEnumerable(),                                                                                                                                     
d2=> d2.Field<string>("key"),                                                                                                                                         
d1=> d1.Field<string>("fKey"),
(d2, d1) => new { d2, d1})
.ToList()
.Select(a=> new {/*your desired fields*/})
```

if you are using ef, u can achieve something similar without extra `.AsEnumrabel()`